# Why do we use "__declspec(dllimport)" when it seems so useless?

Tags: c++, dllimport

Some one told me that if you want to export a library you need use `__declspec(dllexport)`, and when someone uses the library he or she needs to add `__declspec(dllimport)`. But today I found that it is not necessary.

For what reason do we need a `__declspec(dllimport)`?

Comment: Everything you could possibly want to know about DLL export/import: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060727-04/?p=30333

Comment: Because Microsoft.

Comment: Fixed link to _Raymond Chen's DLL imports and exports series_: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060727-04/?p=30333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fskxacy.aspx):

> Using `__declspec(dllimport)` is optional on function declarations, but the compiler produces more efficient code if you use this keyword. However, you must use `__declspec(dllimport)` for the importing executable to access the DLL's public data symbols and objects. Note that the users of your DLL still need to link with an import library.

Comment: Thanks. But what I wonder is that what's the "DLL's public data symbols and objects" meaning. You mean the global or the public part in a class, is  that right?

Comment: As well as functions you can export data and classes. That is what is meant by that text.